# Warning while doing setup CakePHP project

Tags: php, cakephp, installation

I was just setting a cake Project in my system.

But, its showing me these errors:

```
Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306]

Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306]

Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306]
```

Tried many things as I got while searching. But, nothing worked in my case.
I have tried all these:

- 777 permission to tmp folder and its sub folder
- changed the user of the project same as apache user
- Restart apache2 server
- also given 777 permission to whole project
- Done correct db setting in config/database.php

But, still same problem exist. Please help me what I am missing?

Comment: You need to give permissions 777 to app/tmp and all sub folders of tmp.
you can run command 
    sudo chmod -R 777 app/tmp/*

Comment: @NaveedRamzan: Thanks! But,already mention above given 777 permission to tmp folder and its sub folder.

Comment: then you can remove files of tmp/cache/models/* I am sure it will be fixed the issue

Comment: Give permission like `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/cakephp/app/tmp/`

Comment: Given @Sadikhasan
Still its not working!

Comment: I had this problem because the folder `app/tmp/cache/persistent` was missing. Solved it by creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tmp/cache, create two new folder named as 'models' and 'persistent'
Then, you need to give 777 permission to those folders.

Browse, your site it will work. If still not work, then you might need to check in your code there must be written some code related to security.

let me know if still does not work.

Comment: Yes! Worked for me. You are right found some code that was written for security which not allowed me to browse. It might be due to am using ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Change to www-data and change the group of the folder to www-data as well
Then do CHMOD 755.

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997149/3051294)

Hope this works.
Do let me know if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Still getting same err.

Comment: can you do an ls -l on temp?